# How to insert a string which contains commas via a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns : `id`, `food_name`, and `category`.
For example, I have `$food_name = "Amaranth grain, cooked"` (there is a comma), and `category = "Cereals"`.

I can't insert the values and have the following error:

```
Could not connect: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', )' at line 1
```

My SQL query is :

```
$results1 = mysql_query("
  INSERT INTO " . $table . " (food_en, category)
  VALUES ('" . $food_name . "', '" . $category . "')"
)or die(mysql_error());
```

My guess is that the comma in "Amaranth grain, cooked" is posing a problem, but I can't solve it. I tried `str_replace(',', '\,', $food_name)` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` without success. I probably didn't use them right.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I did echo $category, and it's not null nor empty (the value is 'Cereals').**

When I print instead of using mysql_query, I get:

```
INSERT INTO calories (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO carbohydrates (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO fats_and_fatty_acids (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO protein_and_amino_acids (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO vitamins (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO minerals (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO sterols (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')
      INSERT INTO other (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta')Could not connect: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', )' at line 1
```

(the different tables are just different tables I want the line to be inserted into)

Comment: You shouldn't be use `mysql_` functions at all but, rather, PDO or mysqli with parameterized queries.

Comment: I don't think your code could possible generate a query that would produce the error message you posted. There's no `', '` in the error message. The entire second field is completely missing. Are you sure that you posted the code you are actually running?

Comment: replace `mysql_query` with `print` and post what it spits out.

Comment: Your error does not fit to your code. There should be 2 `'` in your error message according to your code: `VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', )'` should be `VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', '')'`

Comment: Where is the "could not connect" coming from? Are you sure you're looking at the right place for the cause of error? Is it possible that the `INSERT INTO other` query might have executed correctly and the error was caused by some other query in some other part of your code?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem in your queries because of comma.
Since you are inserting records to different tables, you need to separate each query with a `query-separator` or `query-delimiter`.

```
INSERT INTO calories (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta'); <-- Notice semi colon at end of query

INSERT INTO carbohydrates (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta'); <-- Notice semi colon at end of query

INSERT INTO fats_and_fatty_acids (food_en, category)
      VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', 'Cereal Grains and Pasta'); <-- Notice semi colon at end of query
```

In the example fiddle, I have separated each query with a `semi-colon` and the queries get inserted without issues.

Refer Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec94bc/1

Answer (score 0):

As long as the string is wrapped in quotes (as you have here in single quotes) then you can have commas in your string. The actual error probably has to do with the fact that $category seems to be either empty string or null since it says:

```
VALUES ('Amaranth grain, cooked', )
```

Make sure you echo out the sql query to make sure it's all exactly as you would expect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use php function addslashes or mysql_real_escape_string to put the slashes before every character which have any meaning in mysql.